# Take Screenshot of current user control or any GUI in Silverlight 3

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I would like to ask if it is possible to take screenshot of current user control programmatically and save as a file in silverlight 3.

I found some ways to save as an image file for a Canvas in silverlight 3, but how about user control or childwindow ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Writable Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) will let you do it. See the samples and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about silverlight 3, but in 4 it's done like this:

```
public static byte[] CreatePngImage(this UIElement element)
{
    WriteableBitmap screenshot = new WriteableBitmap(element, new TranslateTransform());
    var image =  screenshot.ToImage();
    ImageTools.IO.Png.PngEncoder png = new ImageTools.IO.Png.PngEncoder();

    using (var mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        png.Encode(image, mem);
        var bytes = mem.GetBuffer();
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

where ImageTools.IO.Png.dll could be found [here](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/)