# Can I programmatically capture snapshot of a Silverlight User Control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, bitmap

In an ASP.NET MVC app I need to use bitmap images of some of my Silverlight application's User Controls.

Is it possible to generate such images programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not a big deal.

Have a look here: [Take Screenshot of current user control or any GUI in Silverlight 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951371/take-screenshot-of-current-user-control-or-any-gui-in-silverlight-3)

BR,

TJ

Answer (score 4):

If Writeable Bitmap isn't appropriate for you, check out the [ImageTools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/), project on codeplex, where you can save and import images in multiple formats.