# Save Chart as an image on Hard Drive

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I am looking for ways to save the output of a Chart control as an image on the hard drive. Is it possible in SL? as I am not sure so thought of putting a question here..

Thanks...

Comment: What chart control are you using?

Comment: I am using BarSeries for this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look here: [Can I programmatically capture snapshot of a Silverlight User Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689953/can-i-programmatically-capture-snapshot-of-a-silverlight-user-control/4690004#4690004)

You can simply take a screenshot of your chart. If you want to put in on the HD with silverlight you need to open a SaveFileDialog. Then it is possible.

EDIT: If you want to save it in different formats use ImageTools. http://imagetools.codeplex.com/. If you use ImageTools you can get a stream like this:

```
var editBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1024, 786);
            editBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)(this.RenderSize.Width), (int)(this.RenderSize.Height));
            editBitmap.Render(this, new MatrixTransform());
            editBitmap.Invalidate();

            var myImage = editBitmap.ToImage();
            Stream stream = myImage.ToStreamByExtension("png");
```

Hope this helps.

BR,

TJ

Comment: Hi TJ, How to save this WriteableBitmap Class using SaveFileDialog. Here this is the main problem. I can easily convert the Chart to WriteableBitmap object.. WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(this.Column2, null);.. Where Column2 is the Chart object.. Now how to convert this WriteableBitmap to a StreamReader. I Believe that once this is done.. saving the file via SaveFileDialog would be cake walk.. :)

Comment: Thanks TJ.. That did the job for me.. :)